# toyota corolla 2006 cruise control install

Tags: toyota, corolla, cruise-control

I am trying to install cruise control in my drive by wire 1ZZ-FE zze122r toyota corolla. Currently the clockspring is not populated with pins for this install. Does anyone know if my ECU supports cruise and if so which pins connect to the cruise unit? I've found a couple of conflicting circuit diagrams online so would like to clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What market are you in? ECM pinouts may be different. In the US pin 24 connector E5 on the ECM is used for CCS input.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I am in the Australian market. Does anyone know if the ecm pinouts on the Australian model were different? I may just try running the cruise to the e5 pin and see if it works